# Asp.net core web app - pass id and model to edit action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am relatively new to asp.net mvc. My project is using clean architecture with repository and UnitOfWork patterns (I know repository pattern is largely debated these days, and that is no concern for this question). It has an asp.net core web api project and a separate MVC core project.

In the api, I have an updateModel action that expects an id to be passed in the URL, and the model to be passed in the body:

```
        [HttpPut("update-book/{id}")]
        public IActionResult UpdateBook(int id, [FromBody] ComicBookViewModel book)
        {
            try
            {
                var b = _unitOfWork.ComicBooks.GetBookById(id);
                if (b != null)
                {
                    _unitOfWork.ComicBooks.UpdateBook(id, book);
                    return Accepted(book);
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound($"Book with id {id} not found");   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, $"{ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

In the MVC app, I have a page that calls the API and displays a list of entities from the database. Each entity has an edit button. The edit button calls this action in the controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditComic(int id)
        {
            ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel? model = null;
            string uri = $"https://localhost:5001/api/ComicBook/get-book-by-id/{id}";
            HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(
                    name: "ComicbookInventory.Api");

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                model = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel>();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

and then displays a simple edit page:

```
@model ComicBookInventory.Shared.ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditComic";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Edit @Model?.Title</h1>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="EditComic">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsRead" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsRead)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateRead" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateRead" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateRead" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Rating" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Rating" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CoverUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CoverUrl" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CoverUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @*<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" />*@
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="GetAllComics">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The submit button at the bottom of the edit page then calls this action in the controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditComic(ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel model)
        {
            var userId = Request.HttpContext.Request;
            string uri = $"https://localhost:5001/api/ComicBook/update-book/{id}";
            HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(
                    name: "ComicbookInventory.Api");

            var put = client.PutAsJsonAsync<ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel>(uri, model);
            put.Wait();
            var result = put.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("GetAllComics");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

My question is, when this last action is executed, I need to pass the id and model back to the api. How can I accomplish this?

I'm not necessarily looking for answers, just for someone to point me in the right direction. As I said, I'm new to asp.net core MVC apps.. just need some direction.

I don't get any compile-time errors, but if I set a breakpoint in the
EditComic(ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel model) method below, the result is set to http 400 on this line:

var result = put.Result is set to Http 400.

My code is here: https://github.com/rnemeth90/ComicBookInventoryApp

I'm working on the main branch currently.

Comment: Do you get an error?or it just not working??

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated my post with some more details.

Comment: I figured it out just now. I had to mark some properties as nullable in my view model and then re-run the EF core migration to update the db schema. I am not passing these values back to the api from the application in this view (and therefore not passing them to EF core). So that is why I was getting the 400.
 
CharacterIds and AuthorIds are now nullable in this class. Seems to work. Need to test it some more. 
https://github.com/rnemeth90/ComicBookInventoryApp/blob/update-comic-book-from-mvc/src/ComicBookInventory.Domain/Entities/ViewModels/ComicBookViewModel.cs

Comment: Glad you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out just now. I had to mark some properties as nullable in my view model and then re-run the EF core migration to update the db schema. I am not passing these values back to the api from the application in this view (and therefore not passing them to EF core). So that is why I was getting the 400. CharacterIds and AuthorIds are now nullable in this class. Seems to work. Need to test it some more.